# How to create two same name databases in two different mySQL users ?

Tags: mysql

I am using mySQL 5.5 in ubuntu 12.04.
I have created two different users as 'root' and 'abc' and I want to create 'Items' database in this both user accounts but I want this two databases separate.Now my problem is that I have created 'Items' database in root user with 10 tables and when I am trying to create a new user 'abc' then 'Items' database comes automatically in that new user with 10 tables and that is what I don't want to do.

how I can create 2 same name databases in different user accounts with different tables in both DBs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. Database names are be unique per mysql server. (So you cannot have 2 databases with the same name, but for different users)

Comment: But why it is not allowed in two different user accounts ?

Comment: @Akki Because MySQL has not been designed to do that. You create databases, and then assign user permissions to databases/tables/etc. (Many users can access the same database if you tell it to). But there is no ability of the server to create per-user databases.

Comment: @akki - Because it's still the same server. You could quietly prefix the dbs with the respective usernames.

Comment: db creation with same name in different user accounts ?